# How much money should I ask if I want $\$ x $ where there is $20\%$ service charge

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is a website that takes me for each product that I sell $20\%$, is there a formula that can calculate this?:

e.g if I want $\$ 75$ to my pocket, what is the price that I should ask in the website?

I know that it will be some number close to $90$ because $0.2\%\cdot \$ 90=\$ 18$ so I get $\$ 72$

can someone please give me a formula for this calculation?

Comment: Huh, do people really write it like that?  I usually see $\$75$, not $75\$$.

Comment: @SimpleArt This because I'm not American, I edited

Comment: :) That's fine, it just looked strange to me.

Comment: You will get 80% of the price, so you know that 0.8 x = 75. Solve for x.

Comment: @RajatMittal Thank you,I don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is actually simple, since:

$$100\%-20\%=80\%$$

Thus, you'll have

$$80\%\cdot\$x=\$75$$

or,

> $$\$x=\$75/80\%=\$93.75$$